# How do I launch `spark-shell` from the command line?

Tags: command-line, apache2, apache2.4

I installed java scala 2.11.6 and 7 his works but when I type `spark-shell`
it says command not found.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you are reposting this only three hours after you already posted a [nearly-identical question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/819774/how-to-launch-spark) already, rather than editing the older question you already posted?

Comment: Please do not repost questions; instead, use the [edit feature](http://askubuntu.com/posts/819813/edit) to edit your question so you can add information or such.  Reposting the same question multiple times does not help at all, and in fact can be considered destructive or rude .  I have closed your older question as a duplicate of this one, but next time, just edit your question instead of reposting.

Comment: Can you give the results of: `find $HOME -iname spark-shell` ? If no result from this command try this one as well: `sudo find /usr -iname spark-shell`

Comment: I would like to help, but need responses to the questions already asked by andrew46 and the others.

Comment: @L.D.James find $HOME -iname spark-shell                                                       ome/m1/workspace/spark-1.6.1 (2)/spark-1.6.1/bin/spark-shell
/home/m1/workspace/spark-1.6.1/bin/spark-shell
/home/m1/workspace/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell
/home/m1/.local/share/Trash/files/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2 (copy).6/bin/spark-shell
/home/m1/.local/share/Trash/files/spark-1.6.1/bin/spark-shell

Comment: /home/m1/.local/share/Trash/files/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell
/home/m1/Téléchargements/spark-1.6.1/bin/spark-shell
/home/m1/Téléchargements/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell
/home/m1/Téléchargements/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shel

Comment: here is the result of find $HOME -iname spark-shell

Comment: @andrew.46 if I have to do the

Comment: @L.D.James YOU ARE HERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands should work:

```
cd /home/m1/workspace/spark-1.6.1/bin
./spark-shell
```

I see that you have other copies of `spark-shell` here:

```
/home/m1/workspace/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell
/home/m1/Téléchargements/spark-1.6.1/bin/spark-shell
/home/m1/Téléchargements/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark‌​-shell
/home/m1/Téléchargements/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark‌​-shell
```

and these can be opened using the same pattern I have given in the first example or even entered into your `$PATH` for easier access...